# Difficulty with subset sum java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am having difficulty with the subset sum problem.

First I am trying to find the sum of subset to match my target. First original set S is `[3,4,6,2,15,7,5,1,11]`. I read from a file and store the price in an `ArrayList`. Then I let the user enter an amount, and I sum the subsets to match the amount user enters or give the approximate subset sum that matches or is close to the amount entered.

The algorithm is wrong when I enter `25`. It gives `[3,4,6,2,7,1]`, which is wrong. The target amount 25 has several solutions and are `[4,6,15], [15,7,3], [3,4,6,7,5], [3,4,6,11,1], [3,2,15,5].`

I am trying to find the subsets that sum up to 2 and if possible get the best solution. In my original list, since there are 9 elements, there are 512 combinations of subset. I am having difficulty implementing this in code.

Code:

```
class Subset{
    private ArrayList<Integer> subset;
    private Scanner scan;

    public Subset(String filename) {
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            subset = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            while(scan.hasNext()) {
                String readLine = scan.nextLine();
                int num = Integer.parseInt(readLine.split(" ")[1]);
                subset.add(num);
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            scan.close();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getPrices() {
        return this.subset;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> findSubset(int target) {
        ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < subset.size(); i++) {
            if (sum += subset.get(i) <= target) {
                newList.add(subset.get(i));
                sum += newList.get(i);
            }
        }
        return newList;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       final String FILENAME = "groceries.txt";
       Subset sub = new Subset(FILENAME);
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       ArrayList<Integer> price = sub.getPrices();
       System.out.println("Prices in the list: ");
       System.out.println(price);

       System.out.price("Enter an amount to give you a subset.. ");
       System.out.println("Enter price: ");
       int amount = scan.nextInt();

       ArrayList<Integer> list = sub.findSubset(amount);

       System.out.println("The subset list is: "+list);

       scan.close();
   }
}
```

My groceries.txt file is:

```
bread 3
garlic 4
coke 6
potato 2
candy 15
chicken 7 
banana 5
tomato 1
beef 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is to scan the list, including values as long as they don't give you too big a sum.  It is a "greedy" algorithm, in that it assumes something that looks like it might work, will work.  But you have an existence proof that that doesn't work with this kind of problem (in this case, once you included the 2, you're lost).

As you say in your description: there are a lot of possible combinations, and your programs needs to check more of them.  For example, you could, for each value in the list, try building the subsets of the remaining elements of the list with that one included, and then try those that do not include it.  That will allow you to check all possible subsets.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `findSubset(int target)` is incorrect. This method essentially initializes a value `sum` to zero and then loops through each element in `subset` and adds it to the solution subset if its value plus `sum` is less than or equal to `target`. This algorithm does not account for all subsets in `subset` (it actually doesn't account for any subsets of `subset`, only `subset` as a whole.). Furthermore, this algorithm will return elements in `subset` that have a cumulative sum that is equal to **or less than** `target`.

The obvious approach to solving this problem is to generate every possible subset of `subset`, then loop through every subset, sum up the elements, and return that subset if the sum is equal to `target`. This approach can be improved using dynamic programming by memoizing subset sums.

By the way, you might want to name your set structure as `set` instead of `subset` to avoid confusion. :)

Hope this helps!